# Export tables from R to LaTeX

Tags: r

This is a very basic question but any answers would really help.

My question is are there any package or install requirements for LaTeX in order to be able to export from R to LateX?

I am asking because while I have been able to export html and text files from R, trying to export as LateX doesn't output a file at all. I am simply trying to produce nice looking tables for publication.

E.g

```
xtable(newobject2, type = "latex", file = "filename2.tex")
```

Does nothing, whereas

```
xtable(newobject2, type = "html", file = "filename2.htm")
```

Gives me the desired file output.

Do I need to install MacTex in order for this to work? I am on a Mac

Full Code for reference is below:

```
library(foreign)
library(xtable)
library(stargazer)
chap <- read.csv("chap2.csv", header = TRUE)
new <- chap[c("party", "galtan", "sociallifestyle", "civlib_laworder", "religious_principle", "immigrate_policy", "multiculturalism", "urban_rural", "ethnic_minorities", "deregulation", "nationalism", "econ_interven", "redistribution", "spendvtax", "corrupt_salience", "antielite_salience", "international_security", "environment")]
new2 <- new[1:243, 2:18]
fa1 <- factanal(new2, factors = 4, rotation = "varimax", sort = TRUE)
print(fa1, digits = 3, cutoff = .5, sort = TRUE)

newobject2 <- as.data.frame(unclass(fa1$loadings))
xtable(newobject2, type = "latex", file = "filename2.tex")
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! According to documentation this should work. Please help us help you by posting some more information.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks both. well I suppose I can say that I am trying to export factor analysis output in R. Stargazer and xtable packages do not seem to work directly on that type of object so I have tried to convert to a data frame (newobject2) before passing this to xtable (I also tried stargazer). If it helps I will put my full R code above.

Comment: On my system `xtable(obj)` produces LaTeX output by default, but there's no "file=" option.  I have to do `sink("~/file.tex")` then `xtable(obj)` then `sink()` to get an output file.  I have `xtable` 1.8-2

Comment: Your question about "Do I have to install MacTeX" makes me think you are not already using LaTeX on your machine. If that's the case, then Yes, you *do* have to install MacTeX at least to be able to use the resulting document. You don't need to have MacTeX installed to use the relevant R functionality I don't think, although it seems somewhat pointless to produce LaTeX tables from R if you can't also compile the resulting LaTeX.

Answer (score 29):

Welcome! Look at `?print.xtable`. This works

```
print(xtable(newobject2, type = "latex"), file = "filename2.tex")
```

Comment: This answers the question so it should be the accepted answer!

Comment: What if the table is a longtable to be broken over several pages? Do I need to do the work from my master latex document or from R?

Comment: @skan `print(xtable(newobject2, type = "latex", tabular.environment="longtable"), file = "filename2.tex")`and you will have to load the library longtable.  Or ask a new question with mre

Comment: @nebi is an mre a minimal r example?

Comment: @thymaro I was meaning *minimal reproducible example* (not `r` specific). If it wasn't clear, sorry!

Comment: @nebi n.p. I was just wondering what the acronym stands for. thx.